# What is this output from Yammer Reports @{}

Tags: arrays, xcode, powershell, hashtable

I have this output from Yammer activity that is saved as a csv file

"full_name","privacy","stats"

"All Company","public","@{members=101536; aad_guests=0; updates=0; last_message_id=1756009825615872; last_message_at=2022/05/27 07:42:21 +0000}"

I would like the data from "members" in stats

stats : @{members=1; aad_guests=0; updates=0; last_message_id=; last_message_at=}

```
 $YamMy = import-csv .\YammerGroupInfo.csv | sort "full_name" -Descending 

 Foreach ($YMy in $YamMy){
 $Apples = $YMy.full_name 
 $AppleFruit =$YMy.privacy
 $AppleFruit1 = $YMy | Select-Object -ExpandProperty stats
```

<< no matter if I use -expandproperty or where, getnumerator, I cannot get that "members" count. It always shows blank. If I knew what I am dealing with that would help.

Any help would be appreciated. I just don't know what that output is: hash table, collection of objects, an array, json. I have never ran into this kind of output @{}.

```
**Here is the script to create the csv file**

 $baererToken = "<<<token>>>"
 $yammerBaseUrl = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1"

 Function Get-BaererToken() {
$headers = @{ Authorization=("Bearer " + $baererToken) }
return $headers
 }

 Function Get-YamUsers($page, $allUsers) {
if ($page -eq $null) {
    $page = 1
 }

if ($allUsers -eq $null) {
    $allUsers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
}

$urlToCall = "$($yammerBaseUrl)/groups.json"
$urlToCall += "?page=" + $page;

$headers = Get-BaererToken

Write-Host $urlToCall
$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $urlToCall –Method Get -Headers 
 $headers

if ($webRequest.StatusCode -eq 200) {
    $results = $webRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json

    if ($results.Length -eq 0) {
        return $allUsers
    }
    $allUsers.AddRange($results)
}

if ($allUsers.Count % 50 -eq 0) {
    $page = $page + 1
    return Get-YamUsers $page $allUsers
}
else {
    return $allUsers
}
}
 $users = Get-YamUsers
 $users | Select-Object id, name, full_name, web_url, privacy, 
  external, state, creator_id, created_at, last_message_at, stats | 
   Export-Csv f:\tmp\YammerGroupInfo.csv - 
   NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.2)?

Comment: Show us how you create the CSV in the first place - it'll be much easier to fix it at that point rather than trying to salvage the current CSV file

Comment: Here is the script